# File System-like TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate in WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class DirectoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public ObservableCollection<DirectoryViewModel> SubDirectoryList { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> FileList { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }
```

Under each directory, there may be it's own files as well as sub-directories. How can I make both of it's sub-directories and files display on a same level of a TreeView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your class like this:

```
public class DirectoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ItemsInDirectory { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

`ViewModelBase` has to be the base class of `DirectoryViewModel` and `FileViewModel`. Put all your files and directories into the `ItemsInDirectory` collection.

Then create 2 `HierarchicalDataTemplates` one for class `DirectoryViewModel` and one for `FileViewModel`

Comment: thanks! I'm working on silverlight, which don't have **DateType** property for **HierarchicalDataTemplates**, is it possible for creating 2 HierarchicalDataTemplates one for class DirectoryViewModel and one for FileViewModel?

Comment: right the DataType parameter is not available in SL. I never dealt with this unfortunately... Maybe you can use a common HierarchicalDataTemplate for both directory and file and then use converters to deal with things that are not common. (eg. an icon or a popup menu)

Comment: @x0r: Does SL have the concept of a template selector?  You might just have to roll your own implementation.

Comment: @Will: AFAIK silverlight does not have template selectors.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have both DirectoryViewModel and FileViewModel derive from the same TreeViewItemBase class.  Then use have one collection rather than two, and let each derived member deal with its own particularities (like how to, if at all, get child members.  What icon to display, etc)